# Is it possible to create a statement in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can I create a statement in python 2.7?

Something similar to the print statement, that it's like a function, but gets the parameters without parenthesis.

Comment: You can do something sort of like that by defining properties. See the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)—although you can't pass arguments.

Comment: You can do that by forking a python interpreter, or writing your own. But it wouldn't be a python interpreter anymore.